# find an image and add a style, doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an image that need to be removed, but I can't have access to touch the html code, the only way is to using JQuery. So I tried to find the image and given the image as display none but it doesn't get work...

```
$('td.Headerbg').find('img').css('display', 'none');
```

the class contained td which is a part of nested table like this..

```
 <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="Headerbg">
                            <img src="images/header.gif" alt="" />

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </td>
        </tr>
```

Is my code running on wrong way?

Looking forward to your replies..

Comment: Sorry its my mistake, I have made edits. This is the code really what I'm having..

Comment: Do you want to hide or remove the image? hide() hides, remove() removes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector will work with the code you have provided. Make sure you are running your jQuery code at the end of the HTML document (just before the closing `</body>` tag) or running it within a `document.ready` event handler:

```
$(function () {
    $('.Headerbg').find('img').css('display', 'none');
});
```

If you run your code before the DOM elements are available then the `$('.Headerbg')` won't select anything and nothing will happen, this is why it is important to use the `document.ready` event handler or to put you code at the end of your HTML document (which is the best way, it will allow your page to load more quickly).

If you are just running this code when the page loads then you could also use CSS which won't have any flickering of the images, they will just always be hidden:

```
.Headerbg img {
    display : none;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you go with the JavaScript or the CSS solution?

Comment: used Javascript, I can't give display none in CSS, bcoz its using some other pages too.. what I did is included the code inside function that works.

Comment: Just so you know one more thing I missed is the important one document.ready, after adding document.ready it works cool.

Answer (score 0):

For your HTML above, this should work:

```
$('td.Headerbg').find('img').hide();
```

Comment: `.hide()` is a short-cut for `.css('display', 'none')`. Also the question has been updated with the correct class name in the HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm... surely, it's not this simple, but based on your code, the answer is obvious. You're selecting `td.Headerbg`, but your td's class is `bgHeaderBarcart`. Of course it doesn't work.